Accessing snowflake using snowpark java API: merge function giving error Object 'SNOWPARK_TEMP_TABLE_<somename>' does not exist or not authorized
I am trying to connect to snowflake using snowpark Java API with ACCOUNTADMIN access, I am getting below error when i try to merge. Is there something wrong i am doing.
public class MovieRatings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("URL", "URL");
        properties.put("USER", "USER");
        properties.put("PASSWORD", "PWD");
        properties.put("ROLE", "ACCOUNTADMIN");
        properties.put("DB", "INFO");
        properties.put("SCHEMA", "KRISH");
        properties.put("JDBC_QUERY_RESULT_FORMAT", "JSON");
        Session session = Session.builder().configs(properties).create();
        
        Updatable dfFull = session.table("RATINGS1");
        DataFrame df = session.table("RATINGS1_MOVIE_328");

        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = df.toLocalIterator();

        // Create a list to store the updated rows
        ArrayList<Row> updatedRows = new ArrayList<>();

        StructType schema = df.schema();
        int x = 0;


        // Iterate over the rows of movie with id 328 and set ratings to random numbers
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Object[] updatedValues = new Object[schema.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < schema.size(); i++) {
                if (schema.get(i).name().equalsIgnoreCase("RATING")) {
                    // Update the value of the column you want to modify
                    updatedValues[i] = getUpdatedValue(row.get(i));
                } else {
                    // Keep the original value for other columns
                    if(schema.get(i).dataType().equals(DataTypes.StringType))
                    {
                        updatedValues[i] = row.getString(i);
                    }else if (schema.get(i).dataType().equals(DataTypes.FloatType))
                    {
                        updatedValues[i] = row.getFloat(i);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Create a new row with the updated values
            Row updatedRow = Row.create(updatedValues);

            updatedRows.add(updatedRow);
            x++;
        }


        System.out.println("After end of while loop Time: " + formatter.format(date));

      

        System.out.println("updatedRows size: " + updatedRows.size());       
        DataFrame updatedDf = session.createDataFrame(updatedRows.toArray(new Row[0]), schema);

        updatedDf = session.table("RATINGS1_MOVIE_328");


        System.out.println("Before MERGE");


        MergeBuilder mb = dfFull.merge(updatedDf,dfFull.col("USERID").equal_to(updatedDf.col("USERID")).and(dfFull.col("MOVIEID").equal_to(updatedDf.col("MOVIEID"))));
        Map<String, Column> assignments = new HashMap<>();
        assignments.put("RATING", updatedDf.col("RATING"));
      

        try{
            MergeResult mr = mb.whenMatched().updateColumn(assignments).collect();
            System.out.println("getRowsUpdated " + mr.getRowsUpdated() + " getRowsDeleted "+ mr.getRowsDeleted() + " getRowsInserted " + mr.getRowsInserted() );            
            System.out.println("After MERGE");

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            // Close the session
            session.close();
        }
    }

    private static Object getUpdatedValue(Object o) {
        int min1 = 1;
        int max1 = 10;        
        return BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.random()*(max1-min1+1)+min1);        
    }



As you can see the below error in the logs is related to SNOWPARK_TEMP_TABLE_SDRIB42LDGFNG8G (which is most likely a temporary table created by snowpark). I tried to check without using the temprorary dataframe and i didnt get the error, it went fine. The problem seems to be related to the temporary dataframe which is created and being used in the merge. Is there something i am doing wrong? My requirement is row-by-row processing of snowflake table based on some criteria (where condition).
[main] ERROR com.snowflake.snowpark.internal.ServerConnection - failed to execute query:
MERGE  INTO RATINGS1 USING ( SELECT "USERID" AS "r_eTOa_USERID", "MOVIEID" AS "r_eTOa_MOVIEID", "RATING" AS "r_eTOa_RATING", "TIMESTAMP" AS "r_eTOa_TIMESTAMP" FROM ( SELECT "USERID", "MOVIEID", to_decimal("RATING", 38, 4) AS "RATING", "TIMESTAMP" FROM ( SELECT  *  FROM (SNOWPARK_TEMP_TABLE_SDRIB42LDGFNG8G)))) ON (("USERID" = "r_eTOa_USERID") AND ("MOVIEID" = "r_eTOa_MOVIEID")) WHEN  MATCHED  THEN  UPDATE  SET "RATING" = "r_eTOa_RATING"
net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error:
Object 'SNOWPARK_TEMP_TABLE_SDRIB42LDGFNG8G' does not exist or not authorized.

The error says that a table "does not exist or not authorized" - but I guess the table should exist because it was created in the background. Can you share more debug logs that Snowflake shows when you go see queries executed on behalf of this code?

Thanks Felipe for the response. The query history doesnt have more details, pls find the screenshot posted in the post above for your reference.

Thanks for the screenshot. Now, before this query there must be another query in the log attempting to create the missing table. Can you show more of the previous queries in the log? Also please show more of your code.

Hi Felipe,
I updated the full code in the original post. I couldnt locate any query related to creating the temporary snowpark table in the query history. With respect to the code shared it is the full logic (excluding the snowflake session details) i am trying to run. The problem i am facing is when i tried to create a new data frame by iterating the existing dataframe and updating a column in each row by a random value. My requirement is row-by-row processing of snowflake table based on some criteria (where condition). Thank You.
